# how to set selected option based on result set value in select box using jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

i'm getting user table values from database using the following code

```
 <%
String userid=(String)session.getAttribute("userid");
Connection con=Singleton.getMySqlConnection();
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from user where mail='"+userid+"'");
%>
```

and display the values in jsp page like

```
<%while(rs.next()){%>

     <div class="divRegTableColF"><label for="USER_FIRST_NAME">First name: </label></div>
     <%if((rs.getString(2))!=null){%>
     <div class="divRegTableColS"><span> <input class="inputRegBox" name="fname" id="USER_FIRST_NAME" size="60" maxlength="50" value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>"></span>
     </div>
     <%}
     else
     {%>
     <input class="inputRegBox" name="fname" id="USER_FIRST_NAME" size="60" maxlength="50" value=""></span><span class="astRegPad"><font color="#000000">*</font>
     <%}%>


<select class="inputRegBox" name="country" size=1 maxlength=30 value="<%=rs.getString(13)%>">   
    <option>select</option>
    <option >Afghanistan</option>
    <option >Aland Islands</option>
    <option>Albania</option>
    <option>Algeria</option>
    <option>American Samoa</option>
    <option>Andorra</option>
    <option>Angola</option>
    <option>Anguilla</option>
    <option>Antarctica</option>
    <option>Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option>Argentina</option>
    <option>Armenia</option>
    <option>Aruba</option>
    <option>Australia</option>
    <option>Austria</option>
    <option>Azerbaijan</option>
    <option>Bahamas</option>
    <option>Bahrain</option>
    <option>Bangladesh</option>
    <option>Barbados</option>
    <option>Belarus</option>
    <option>Belgium</option>
    <option>Belize</option>
    <option>Benin</option>
    <option>Bermuda</option>
    <option>Bhutan</option>
    <option>Bolivia</option>
    <option>Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba</option>
    <option>Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option>Botswana</option>
    <option>Bouvet Island</option>
    <option>Brazil</option> 
</select>
</div></div>
   </div>
<%}%>


enter code here
```

i'm getting the country value in select box.how to selected option value and display that value in select box.

Comment: Where is the value to match? I mean based on which value you need to select the dropdown value?

Comment: In your option tags you are missing `value` element.

Comment: i'll add value element in <option> tag after that how to check that and display country based on ResultSet value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add condition in option selected tag, since am not jsp developer, But easily you will add all the option value in array and execute,

```
<select class="inputRegBox" name="country" size=1 maxlength=30 >   
    <option value="Afghanistan"  <%if((rs.getString(13))=='Afghanistan'){%> selected <%}%> >Afghanistan</option>
</select>
```